# iPhone: provisioning profile expiring every 2 months? 

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is it just me or do the provisioning profiles created on the developer portal expire every 2 months? Why is that insanity?

Is there any way to create a provisioning profile that will last for the entire period of the annual subscription?

I have contacted Apple, but they simply did not answer. Is Apple insane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provisioning Profiles have shorter lifetimes now, yes.

I don't think Apple is insane, they probably have a good reason for it. Does it jive with what you want out of life? It appears not, but I would think that they have a legitimate reason for wanting to change the limitations and it is not because of a lack of sanity. Besides, Apple would have to be collectively nuts and I don't think that that is the case or even really possible.

It barely takes a moment to renew an expired one, and then each developer on your team has to update as well - and that also barely takes a moment.

Most iPhone app dev cycles probably hover around the 2 month range anyway so this shouldn't be a big deal to most.

So like the guy in that PS3 commercial - gonna file this one under not an issue.