# How long does a provisioning profile last for testing?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

When I install it on my own device, the profile says it expires **one year** after the last time I changed it. But I also heard it could be shorter. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848485/iphone-provisioning-profile-expiring-every-2-months) the times 2 months and 3 months are mentioned. Which is correct and why?

I need a testrun that is around 3-4 months. If I let my tester install my beta app, using a provisioning profile for development, how long will she be able to run the application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Till the provisioning profile expires...You can check out when they expire in the provisioning portal, or if it is installed on the device, under settings->general->profiles

Comment: thx, I updated my question. So my testers will be able to run my app for a year?

Comment: Ok great =) But then why are the folks over at question 1848485 (linked above) saying "2 months" and "3 months"?

Comment: Well i think the team profiles are a year, the ones that u just create are 2-3 months, also if you creat adhoc ones then those last a year

Comment: None of the Provisioning Profiles on my device expires that fast. The Team Provisioning Profiles expires in a year from when I created them, and the profile named like my app is expiring a year from when I edited it a few days ago. Is this because I am using it for development from Xcode? Will my testers have earlier expiration dates than me?

Comment: Your testers will have same expiration date as the profile... and team provisioning profiles tend to last a year like i said...and if non of your profiles expire fast then thats good, problem solved... Whatever the profile says on it is the expiration date for everyone

Comment: You were right, it lasts as long for them as it does for me. At least it says so in the Settings. :)

Comment: Settings > General > Profiles is not there on iOS 11. Has this moved? Can this still be found on the phone?